# Объединение меток [discord-py] и [discord.py]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Есть две метки [discord-py](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord-py)(<s>395</s> <s>668</s> 854 вопросов) и [discord.py](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.py)(<s>57</s> <s>434</s> 714 вопроса).  За последний год количество вопросов по 2 метке увеличилось больше чем по первой, поэтому давайте сделаем ее главной!

EDIT: А дублирующую метку пора бы уже и грохнуть )

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/discord-py/synonyms А ещё вот [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested) надо бы чтобы почаще заглядывали.

Comment: У обеих меток есть описание, причём разное. Какое из описаний надо и как официально называется библиотека? Полагаю, если там точка, то надо и в метке делать точку.

Comment: @Qwertiy как насчёт заглянуть по ссылке из моего комментария выше и модераторским решением посиномизировать (хотя бы что-то)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, готово

Comment: Bump. Ну и я бы на вариант с точкой предпочел бы чтобы было слито, все-таки модуль именно так называется.

Comment: Прошло достаточно много времени, вопросов стало 854 и 714 соответственно по этим меткам, хотя их, как я понял, объединили. Что-то произошло и синоним отменили что ли?

Comment: Попробовал улучшить описание [метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/discord.py/info). Думаю, это поможет для объединения.